# PHP COM class not found

Tags: php, com

I'm trying to convert a doc file to pdf using COM class, But its throwing the error

> Fatal Error: Class COM not found

I've tried uncommenting the required extensions in all the php.ini files installed on my computer already.

> [COM_DOT_NET]
>   extension=php_com_dotnet.dll

I've also changed the dir path to the extensions

> On windows:
>   extension_dir ="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/"

Below is my code:
1. I've saved apache office inside the PHP folder.
2.Using WAMP on win7
3. I've also refreshed my local server everytime I update my php.ini file

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
function MakePropertyValue($name,$value,$osm){
$oStruct = $osm->Bridge_GetStruct("com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue");
$oStruct->Name = $name;
$oStruct->Value = $value;
return $oStruct;
}
function word2pdf($doc_url, $output_url){

//Invoke the OpenOffice.org service manager
$osm = new COM("com.sun.star.ServiceManager") or die ("Please be sure that OpenOffice.org is installed.\n");
//Set the application to remain hidden to avoid flashing the document onscreen
$args = array(MakePropertyValue("Hidden",true,$osm));
//Launch the desktop
$oDesktop = $osm->createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop");
//Load the .doc file, and pass in the "Hidden" property from above
$oWriterDoc = $oDesktop->loadComponentFromURL($doc_url,"_blank", 0, $args);
//Set up the arguments for the PDF output
$export_args = array(MakePropertyValue("FilterName","writer_pdf_Export",$osm));
//print_r($export_args);
//Write out the PDF
$oWriterDoc->storeToURL($output_url,$export_args);
$oWriterDoc->close(true);
}

$output_dir = "C:/wamp/www/";
$doc_file = "C:/wamp/www/reportdoc.docx";
$pdf_file = "reportpdf.pdf";

$output_file = $output_dir . $pdf_file;
$doc_file = "file:///" . $doc_file;
$output_file = "file:///" . $output_file;
word2pdf($doc_file,$output_file);
?>
```

I've tried possibly every solution, but still without any help.

Answer (score 0):

So it can be a bunch of things:

1. Ensure your php_com_dotnet.dll is in the extension_dir defined by the php.ini(no brainer I know but still).
2. Try changing new COM to 
       $osm = new \COM("com.sun.star.ServiceManager") or die ("Please be sure that OpenOffice.org is installed.\n"); 
   (if you're using a separate namespace this might fix the issue).
3. In your php.ini, try setting extension_dir="ext" if you're using wamp. (the extension dir in wamp is usually under the active php version and in the ext folder)

Save the php file and restart wamp and hopefully one of these will do the trick for you.